# Why is my return value not holding a value in my main method?

Tags: java, return-value

The issue I am having is where the break in my code is. I have commented out sections too see where it breaks and cannot seem to find it. What happens now is, once the stringMethod is called the for loop does nothing and b is never used. I'm not sure why a isn't holding the same value from my method. Any help is appreciated and if I wasn't clear about something, just ask.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestTwoClassMain {
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String j = "", b = "", c = "", a = "";

    do {
        stringMethod();

        for (int i = j.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            b = b + a.charAt(i);
//the above 'a' is not holding any value for the sentence entered in method

        System.out.println("Reverse: " + b);
        System.out.print("Try Again? ");
        c = input.nextLine();
    } while (c.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
}

public static String stringMethod() {
    String a = "";
    System.out.print("Enter: ");
    a = input.nextLine();
    return a;
}

}
```

Comment: You can get more idea why the value should be returned, by looking at articles that explains Pass by Values and Pass by References in Java. Java uses pass by values, which is a good read to understand how it works.

Comment: You can get more idea why the value should be returned, by looking at articles that explains Pass by Values and Pass by References in Java. Java uses pass by values, which is a good read to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign your `a` variable to the output of stringMethod()

```
a = stringMethod()
```

You need to do this because you've declared `a` within the scope of your main method, as opposed to declaring it within the scope of the class.